# Disable Google Play Developer Console Alert

Tags: google-play, alert

After having my app update rejected I keep seeing that alert when I log in to Google Play Developer Console:
[image]

I already unpublished an app that was rejected about 3 months ago, but I'm still seeing this every time I log in.

Is there a way to get rid of this banner or it will stay there forever as after that long period of time it's getting really irrelevant and I have to check every app manually if everything is fine.